# Blank screen after wrongly modifying profile file

Tags: display-resolution, monitor

With a new monitor, I changed the resolution and in order to make it permanent, I added a couple of lines in the profile file as mentioned on the forum.
Except that now I am having the problem of black screen and cannot even get to the terminal: ctrl-alt-F1 or ctrl-alt-F2 do work. 
I only reach the point of selecting the user and then blank screen

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons that are just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is 18.04 or newer...

- if you can get to the console tty with ctrl-alt-F1 or ctrl-alt-F2
- enter username/password

or

- At the GRUB menu, select Additional Options
- choose the newest-kernel recovery mode
- drop to root access
- enter root password if required

then

- `cd /home/username`
- `sudo pico .profile`
- undo/repair your prior edits
- save the file
- log out/log in or `reboot`

Comment: this is indeed newer than 18.04, but:

Comment: @PhilippeScheimann but what?

Comment: sorry, I thought I had written all... I get to the point where I put my password, then I cant get to the console (crtl alt f1/2 ) do not work, and I dont know how to get to the GRUB menu (I only have ubuntu on this machine)

Comment: @PhilippeScheimann  Your GRUB menu must be hidden. To show it, hold down the SHIFT (for older BIOS computer), or ESC (for newer UEFI computer), right when you see the BIOS splash screen, or immediately there after, then you can continue with my answer.

Comment: @PhilippeScheimann status please...

Comment: I've been trying with no success: I cannot access the GRUB menu - I hold down SHIFT or ESC with no success. Maximum: I receive the menu that asks me to enter my password of ubuntu.

Comment: @PhilippeScheimann Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, then use the `Files` app to mount your HDD, navigate to your home directory, then try and edit .profile.

Comment: I've finally been able to open the GRUB menu, I am not familiar with linux instructions: I am at root@user-desktop:~# , how do I "drop to root access " , thanks for your patience

Comment: @PhilippeScheimann root@user-desktop:~# is the prompt for the root user... so you're there. Now follow the instructions in the third part of my answer. Good luck!